# International Hunger Crisis

Tags: wordplay, visual, knowledge, language, geography

1. Study the Inkblot Test.
2. Read the anecdote.
3. **Determine the name of the establishment.**

   ---

[image]
<sub>Blots are not necessarily scaled relative to each other.</sub>

---

> So I was *really* {3} one day, so {3} off to get me a {5} sandwich.
>
> I told the guy behind the counter,"I don't mean to {3}, but I heard {3} really good sandwich here, is that right?"
>
> He said: "{5} wait a sec? You haven't even taken a number yet!"
>
> There was this {5} skateboard, wearing a {3} tie looking at the rotisserie. I said, "I can't see the display. Can {4} your neck and {5} what it says?"
>
> He ignored me. "What's this, then? They just stick meat on a {3} drip {5} on it?"
>
> I responded, "Yeah, that stuff can really {2} the flavor."
>
> I heard the lunch-man asking a customer: "Do you want this order {3} or should I put it on a {3} plate for you?"
>
> As I was leaving the store that {4} afternoon, I realized that I didn't get any change. {1} me!
>
> That's OK. I'm just happy to know that my sandwich {2}. Authentic food is the only kind {2}!

Comment: The answer is "No." The answer at the end of the penultimate line *does not start with "F."*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Complete answer -

Letters/blots:

> ```
> A  Chile
> B  Isle of Man (Thanks @TobySpeight and @m1gp0z)
> C  Guyana
> D  Ukraine
> E  Turkey
> F  Sudan
> G  Togo
> H  Israel
> I  Poland
> J  China
> K  Czech (Republic)
> L  Jamaica
> M  Sweden
> N  Russia
> O  Hungary
> P  Greece
> Q  Iran
> R  Kenya
> S  Egypt
> ```

Anecdote:

> So I was really **huNgary** one day, so **irAn** off to get me a **turkEy** sandwich.
> I told the guy behind the counter,"I don't mean to **ruSsia**, but I heard **jaMaica** really good sandwich here, is that right?"
> He said: "**kenyA** wait a sec? You haven't even taken a number yet!"
> There was this **guyaNa** skateboard, wearing a **suDan** tie looking at the rotisserie. I said, "I can't see the display. Can **ukrAine** your neck and **czecH** what it says?"
> He ignored me. "What's this, then? They just stick meat on a **poLand** drip **greeCe** on it?"
> I responded, "Yeah, that stuff can really **sWeden** the flavor."
> I heard the lunch-man asking a customer: "Do you want this order **toGo** or should I put it on a **chIna** plate for you?"
> As I was leaving the store that **chiLe** afternoon, I realized that I didn't get any change. **Egypt** me!
> That's OK. I'm just happy to know that my sandwich **iSrael**. Authentic food is the only kind **iSle of man**!

Letters ordered by appearance in the anecdote:

> NAESMANDAHLCWGILESS

Letters ordered alphabetically by blot letter:

> LSNAEDGSLIHMWSNCAAE

So...still dunno the final answer.  Terrible attempts below:

> Ham and Swiss Lace Glen
> Nameless Sandwich Gal
> Sand a Legless Manwich
> Changeless Maw Island
> Ms. Lasagna-Chew Island
> Smelling Canada's Welsh
> @Chawssin am SE LLEGAND!!!

For real, though:

> My friend [Sam (and a Legless Winch)] agree that it should actually be
> **Magellan's Sandwiches**

OK, it was actually @aynber!  Thanks for nudging (then shoving) me along.  =)
May you never catch

> Ms. Swanglan's Head Lice

Comment: I had a typo on "P". :( It's been changed to {5}, instead of {4}. Does that help? The story and blots are good!

Comment: @Chowzen Thanks!  I switched out the letter.  I'd love to say it helped, but I'm still stuck on the last country and the establishment.  This is a pretty great puzzle.

Comment: B is a British Crown dependency, but that's not helping me with the letters.

Comment: @hagfy B is Rot13(Vfyr bs Zna) - "..is the only kind rot13(V ybir, zna)"

Comment: @TobySpeight Oh geez, I even thought of that place earlier and never checked the shape.  Thanks!

Comment: My first thought was "to value", but the shape didn't match...

Comment: I think I see a kind of food mentioned in the story, if the letters are to be anagrammed.

Comment: @TobySpeight I also thought of Tuvalu, heh.  An anagram is my assumption, so if you've got a final answer, go ahead and post it!

Comment: It's definitely anagram. If you think of it as the name of a place, you can rearrange the non-food letters to get the rest of the name.

Comment: @aynber Thanks...but clearly **I** can't.  Somebody else should definitely go for it though.

Comment: @hagfy, I dig all those names.  If I had endless resources, I might start each of those as franchises :)

Comment: Is the other word the name of an explorer?  That would make sense, given the "world" theme.

Comment: @TobySpeight are you possibly thinking rot13(Zntryyna'f Fnaqjvpurf)?

Comment: Yes, but aynber beat me to making that an answer.

Comment: I added it to mine and credited you.

Comment: You were the 2nd to answer, first to have all countries and a completed anecdote. If you'll add [the intended name of the establishment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68310/international-hunger-crisis/68318#68318) to your already impressive list, I'll eventually accept this as correct. P.S. If "*Legless* Sandwich Gal" had fit the clues, I'd have had to call the sign company to get it changed. :)

Comment: @hagfy Gaaah, now my head is itchy!

Answer (score 12):

Following @hagfy's answer, the name of the establishment is

> Magellan's Sandwiches

Answer (score 9):

Partial:

The ink blots are mostly as follows:

> A: Chile
> B:
> C: Guyana
> D: Ukraine
> E: Turkey
> F: Sudan
> G: Togo
> H: Israel
> I: Poland
> J: China
> K:
> L:
> M: Sweden
> N: Russia
> O: Hungary
> P: Greece
> Q: Iran
> R: Kenya
> S: Egypt

And the story goes something like

> So I was really {HUNGARY} one day, so {IRAN} off to get me a {TURKEY} sandwich.
> I told the guy behind the counter,"I don't mean to {RUSSIA}, but I heard {?canada (can eat a)?} really good sandwich here, is that right?"
> He said: "{KENYA} wait a sec? You haven't even taken a number yet!"
> There was this {GUYANA} skateboard, wearing a {SUDAN} tie looking at the rotisserie. I said, "I can't see the display. Can {UKRAINE} your neck and {??} what it says?"
> He ignored me. "What's this, then? They just stick meat on a {POLAND} drip {GREECE} on it?"
> I responded, "Yeah, that stuff can really {SWEDEN} the flavor."
> I heard the lunch-man asking a customer: "Do you want this order {TOGO} or should I put it on a {CHINA} plate for you?"
> As I was leaving the store that {CHILE} afternoon, I realized that I didn't get any change. {EGYPT} me!
> That's OK. I'm just happy to know that my sandwich {ISRAEL}. Authentic food is the only kind {?haiti (I eat)?}!

I have yet to figure out the meaning of the numbers in the story, and so am still at a loss when it comes to the name of the establishment.

Comment: Could L be Mongolia?

Answer (score 6):

Countries:

> A. Chile 
>  B. Isle of Man  
>  C. Guyana 
>  D. Ukraine 
>  E. Turkey 
>  F. Sudan 
>  G. Togo 
>  H. Israel 
>  I. Poland 
>  J. China 
>  K. Czech(ia) 
>  L. Jamaica 
>  M. Sweden 
>  N. Russia 
>  O. Hungary 
>  P. Greece 
>  Q. Iran 
>  R. Kenya 
>  S. Egypt

Anecdote:

> So I was really {3} **Hungary** one day, so {3} **Iran** off to get me a {5} **Turkey** sandwich. 
>  I told the guy behind the counter,"I don't mean to {3} **Russia**, but I heard {3} **Jamaica** really good sandwich here, is that right?" 
>  He said: "{5} **Kenya** wait a sec? You haven't even taken a number yet!" 
>  There was this {5} **Guyana** skateboard, wearing a {3} **Sudan** tie looking at the rotisserie. I said, "I can't see the display. Can {4} **Ukraine** your neck and {5} **Czech** what it says?" 
>  He ignored me. "What's this, then? They just stick meat on a {3} **Poland** drip {5} **Greece** on it?" 
>  I responded, "Yeah, that stuff can really {2} **Sweden** the flavor."
>  I heard the lunch-man asking a customer: "Do you want this order {3} **Togo** or should I put it on a {3} **China** plate for you?" 
>  As I was leaving the store that {4} **Chile** afternoon, I realized that I didn't get any change. {1} **Egypt** me! 
>  That's OK. I'm just happy to know that my sandwich {2} **Israel**. Authentic food is the only kind {2} **Isle of Man**!

If we take the {x} to be

> the letter at position x of each country,

we get the following

> set of letters: NAESMANDAHLCWGILESS

which could possibly rearrange to

> SENEGAL SANDWICH SLAM??

or

> Magellan's Sandwiches, based on @Toby Speight's suggestion in previous comments.

Comment: Remark: Sorry everybody, I probably ought to have refreshed this page before posting!

Comment: Personally, I prefer your first suggestion to the second.  I don't know why, probably due to the alliteration